# mysql remove duplicate month

Tags: php, mysql

I want to remove duplicate month

this is my data
[image]

i want remove duplicate and show like this

[image]

this is my code

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    $query = "select * from mydata";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
    while($data  = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $dbasearray[] = $data['month_data'].",".$data['week_data'].",".$data['total_data'];
    }
    $s1 = array();
    $s2 = array();
    $a  = array();
    $b  = array();

    echo "<table border='1'>

            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>s1</th>
                <th>s2</th>
                <th>a</th>
                <th>b</th>
            </tr>
            ";
        foreach ($dbasearray as $index => $datah){

            $data = explode(",", $datah);

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$data[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$data[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$data[2]."</td>";
                if($index==0){
                    echo "<td>".$s1[$index] = $data[2]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$s2[$index] = $data[2]."</td>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<td>".$s1[$index] = 0.1*$data[2]+0.9*$s1[$index-1]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$s2[$index] = 0.1*$s1[$index]+0.9*$s2[$index-1]."</td>";
                }
                echo "<td>".$a[$index] = 2*$s1[$index]-$s2[$index]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$b[$index] = (0.1/0.9)*($s1[$index]-$s2[$index])."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

i don't know to remove/hidden my code, i'm cannot using group by 
help me. Thank's

Comment: Once you've fixed that, you just need to make a minor adjustment to your while loop

Comment: @Strawberry i don't know, this question and module from education in my college

Comment: @Strawberry give me example please :(

Comment: Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

Comment: @natanel97 okay i'm already change to mysqli so, what a solution to remove duplicate month ?

Comment: check my answer. It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion, try printing the stuff inside the while loop itself , instead of storing in another variable and iterating multiple times. After you complete that,

Just do the following. You don't want duplicate months printed.
So, before the while loop add this.

```
$prev_month = '';
```

then inside the while loop you need to input the correct month.

```
   if ($prev_month == $row['month'])
   {
       $month = '';
   }
   $prev_month = $row['month'];
```

Use $month inside your html printing.

The complete code is written below. Check and see if it works.

```
$month = '';
$prev_month = '';
echo "<table border='3'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   echo "<tr>";
   $month = $row['month'];

   if ($prev_month == $row['month'])
   {
       $month = '';
   }
   $week = $row['week'];
   $total = $row['total'];
   $s1 = $row['s1'];
   $s2 = $row['s2'];
   $a = $row['a'];
   $b = $row['b'];

   echo "<td>";
   echo $month ;
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $week ; 
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $total ;
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo  $s1 ;  
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $s2 ; 
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $a ; 
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $b ;
   echo "</td>";



   // Fill up the rest of fields and the print them
   echo "</tr>";
   $prev_month = $row['month'];

}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be abundantly clear from what follows that I'm no PHP coder, but it should give the idea...

Sample data set:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,month INT NOT NULL, user VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (month,user) VALUES 
(1,'Ben'),
(2,'Ben'),
(3,'Tom'),
(1,'Gary'),
(2,'Jessica'),
(3,'Dean'),
(1,'Elizabeth');
```

Sample query and result:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY month,id;
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | month | user      |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |     1 | Ben       |
|  4 |     1 | Gary      |
|  7 |     1 | Elizabeth |
|  2 |     2 | Ben       |
|  5 |     2 | Jessica   |
|  3 |     3 | Tom       |
|  6 |     3 | Dean      |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Sample PHP code...

```
<?php

require('path./to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "SELECT month, user FROM my_table ORDER BY month , id;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$x = null;

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($row['month']==$x)
  { $month = ''; }
  else
  { $month = $row['month'];}

echo "<tr><td>$month</td><td>".$row['user']."</td></tr>";

$x = $row['month'];
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Outputs:

```
1   Ben
    Gary
    Elizabeth
2   Ben
    Jessica
3   Tom
    Dean
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$chkArry=array();
$query = "select * from mydata";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($data  = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $dbasearray[] = $data['month_data'].",".$data['week_data'].",".$data['total_data'];
}
$s1 = array();
$s2 = array();
$a  = array();
$b  = array();

echo "<table border='1'>

        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>s1</th>
            <th>s2</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
        </tr>
        ";
    foreach ($dbasearray as $index => $datah){

        $data = explode(",", $datah);
        if(in_array($data[0], $chkArry)){
            $data[0]='';
        }
        else
         {
            array_push($chkArry, $data[0]);
         }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$data[0]."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$data[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$data[2]."</td>";
            if($index==0){
                echo "<td>".$s1[$index] = $data[2]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$s2[$index] = $data[2]."</td>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<td>".$s1[$index] = 0.1*$data[2]+0.9*$s1[$index-1]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$s2[$index] = 0.1*$s1[$index]+0.9*$s2[$index-1]."</td>";
            }
            echo "<td>".$a[$index] = 2*$s1[$index]-$s2[$index]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$b[$index] = (0.1/0.9)*($s1[$index]-$s2[$index])."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

try above code and let me know if problem still persists.